# How to use calculate and distinct count together in powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I want to count the following in powerpivot.

I have a column with customer numbers and then I have another column with status ("paid", "no")

If any of the customer entries are "paid" I want that to count as 1 unique customer. If not, then there is no count.

For example, 1,1,1 and "paid" "paid" "paid" would be equivalent to 1 count.

I tried this 
Copy of Calculated Field 1:=CALCULATE(Count(Table1[Claim]),Table1[Invoice]="Paid")

but it essentially counted ALL instances of "Paid".

Answer (score 0):

Are you not just looking for a distinct count?

=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1'[Customer_ID]),'Table1'[Invoice]="Paid")